# Adding WMS layer in existing map with ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, wms, arcgis-silverlight-api

We have an existing Silverlight application that loads a ArcGIS MapService and display it to the user. We want to add the ability to also add a WMS layer on top of the existing displayed map. I am not too familiar about WMS layers and the samples i found on ArcGIS are only loading ArcGIS WMS layers.

We have updated one of our ArcGIS map services and enabled the WMS capability.

How do i add the WMS layer to the map?

Would i access it the same as a ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer?

using a url like this? `http://OurArcGISServer/arcgis/services/Map1/MapServer/WMSServer`

Comment: Where is the WMS service coming from? Accordingly I could provide you with a small sample.

Comment: Hi Devdatta, generally we want it to be dynamic(if possible). Example, our city releases or allows of its WMS maps for changes in roads etc.

Comment: What exactly is your issue? What have you tried so far? where are you stuck? I've never had any problem using WMS services in a Silverlight App. There is even an sample in the API help. Unfortunately I'm on a linux machine right now, so Can't link to it.

Comment: Hi Devdatta, from the samples that i have found. It seems that you have to build your own request link every time you try to zoom in/out a WMS layer. I was wondering if there was a similar way like how we load an ArcGISDynamicServiceLayer but on a WMS layer.

Comment: Have you looked at this http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/18836-WMS-layer-in-Silverlight-app it shows how you can have a wmslayer

Comment: Hi, i was just about to test that. I'll let you know how it goes. Thank you very much for you help. :)

Comment: Hi Devdatta, can you add your comment as a post? so that i can mark it as the answer. Also, i was able to accomplish 80% of what i need based from the link that you have provided. Do you also have any ideas on identifying/search/query a wms layer? i think it has to do something with the GetFeatureInfo capabilities of the WMS layer but do i have to manually create a request to use it?

Comment: I've posted my comment as an Answer. As for the identifying/querying of WMS service, AFAIK, the Silverlight API does not have anything for it. You have to create a getFeatureinfo request, and parse the results yourself. Have a look at this: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/12655-identify-on-wms-source I'll suggest that you post any issues with querying/identifying a WMS service as a new question, so that it attracts more attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a WMS service to the Map using a [WMSLayer class](https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/api-reference/#ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources.WmsLayer.html).

Please have a look at [this sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/sample-code/start.htm#WmsLayerSimple), which shows that you can display a WMSLayer in your map, with code like this:

```
<esri:WmsLayer ID="OtherWMSLayer"                      
               Url="http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r.cgi"                     
               ProxyUrl="http://servicesbeta3.esri.com/SilverlightDemos/ProxyPage/proxy.ashx"                     
               SkipGetCapabilities="False"                     
               Layers="nexrad-n0r" 
               Version="1.1.1" 
               Opacity="0.7" />
```

You should also have a look at [this thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/18836-WMS-layer-in-Silverlight-app) on the ArcGIS forums.

Comment: The last link appears to be broken.